# Round a float to same decimals as the multiplier

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like someone's help in writing this in the most pythonic way possible

```
x = 2.651
y = 1.05
a = x * y
print(a)
2.78355
```

In this example, I want `a` to have the same number of decimals as `x`, so the answer should be 2.784. What is a pythonic way to get to this answer with the right number of decimals?

Comment: `x` doesn't have any number of decimal places, internally it's a binary floating-point number _approximately_ equal to `2.651` in decimal — so your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @martineau OP might want to use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module, eh?

Comment: @wjandrea: Yes, I think it might be possible with the `decimal` module (but am not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. My trick uses string properties.

```
x = 2.651
y = 1.05

x_dec = len(str(x).split('.')[1])

a = ('{0:.%df}' % x_dec).format(x * y)
```

Comment: I wondered if you could do a double format, and it turns out you can! `'{{0:.{:d}f}}'.format(x_dec).format(x * y)`. Pretty ugly tho. In practice I would probably use `round()` like in [brazosFX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540088/4518341)

Comment: @Unknown Coder: Try it with `x = 2.650000000000000000000001`

Comment: You are right but this is a bigger known problem and not really related with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 2.651
decloc = (str(x).find('.'))+1
decimals = (len(str(x)[decloc:]))
y = 1.05
a = x * y
print(round(a, decimals))
```

Comment: Obviously you can just make a def out of those added lines and pass each float into it to get length of decimal places.

Comment: x_dec = len(str(x).split('.')[1]) in Luca's answer is far more pythonic, and just better.  Replaces my 2 lines called 'decloc' and 'decimals'